# How to track monthly subscription usage of user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have the scenario where I have three models:

1. Subscription Model
2. User Model (Has Subscription Model ForeignKey)
3. Match Model (Has User Model ForeignKey)

Users can choose to sign up for 6 month/ 12 month/ 18 month subscriptions where they can have a maximum of 10 matches PER MONTH.

Users may start the subscription on any given date of the month.

My question is how do I track how many matches are assigned to the user in a given month(with the first date of the month being the date he signed up on)?
How do I reset the number of matches back to 10 after every month finishes?

Following are the models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    Membership = models.ForeignKey('Membership.MonthlyMembership', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default="", null=True,  blank=True)
    MembershipStart = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Membership Start Date")

class Match(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Report_Url = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class MonthlyMembership(models.Model):
    MonthlyMembershipName = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Monthly Membership')
    MatchesPerMonth = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Matches Per Month')
    NumberOfMonths = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Number of months this subscription will last")
```

Comment: So, you want to reset the `User.MonthlyMembership. MatchesPerMonth` to 10 after the completion of a month?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to reset the MatchesPerMonth back to 10. But this should take place every month from MembershipStart on the user model till NumberOfMonths length(6 months, 12 months, etc.)

Comment: Why store the value `MatchesPerMonth`? You can simply calculate that by a query.